# How to join parent and child record with script in elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

```
"parentrecord": {
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type":"integer"
        },  
        "parentDate":{
            "type":"date"
        }
    }
},  
"childrecord": {
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type":"integer"
        },
        "childDate":{
            "type":"date"
        }
    },
    "_parent": {
        "type":"parentrecord"
    }
}
```

I want to get the average of the difference between parentDate and childDate using script in Elasticsearch.

I am not able connect between child and parent within script.

Note: childDate is always greater than parentdate.

Answer (score 0):

Joining a parent and child field is not possible in ElasticSearch. Read about the feature request [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/1017). ElasticSearch treats Parent and Child Types in a similar way. While you can query from both as normal, ES just maintains a relationship between 2 different types by using _parent field in the type mapping structure. To join a parent field and child field, ElasticSearch will have to look up another document from within the script and this is considered to be an expensive operation.